# Access error logs in Vagrant box to view 'internal server errors'

Tags: php, magento, error-handling, vagrant

I have a vagrant box setup that and would like to debug some '500 internal server' errors I am receiving in Magento application

I see the log folder within my directory structure but cannot see any access.log or error.log files within this directory do I need to something to turn this on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember the log files for errors is exception.log, and notice/warnings is system.log. Both files are under var/log of your magento installation.

Sometimes magento can not catch an error. In this case the error is either printed to the browser or saved to the Apache log. Checkout the apache log under /var/log/apache/ (file name may be pho_error.log, error.log as set in apache vhost config.